# Error when looking up max value from a python dictionary : max() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to filter a dictionary and find the max from a list of values. Here a sample dictionary:

```
import numpy as np

def clean_currency(x):
""" If the value is a string, then remove currency symbol and delimiters
otherwise, the value is numeric and can be converted
"""
    if isinstance(x, str):
       return(x.replace('$', '').replace(',', ''))
    return(x)



d = {
     'shores': ['$0.00'],
     'Broderick': ['$0.00', '$0.00', '$0.00'],
     '100 Broderick': ['$0.00', '$1,142,070.00', '$0.00', '$0.00', '$0.00'],
     '1001 Orange Grove': ['$0.00'],
     '1008 Hyde': [np.nan]
    }


# Keep the highest value from the list. 

revd = {
        k: max((e for e in v if pd.notna(e)), key=lambda x: float(clean_currency(x)) if isinstance(x, str) else x)
        for k,v in d.items()
       }

revd
```

I am getting `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence` error.

Full traceback

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/d0/gnksqzwn2fn46fjgrkp6045c0000gn/T/ipykernel_49841/938463883.py in <module>
      1 # Keep the highest value from the list.
      2 
----> 3 revd = {
      4         k: max((e for e in v if pd.notna(e)), key=lambda x: float(clean_currency(x)) if isinstance(x, str) else x)
      5         for k,v in d.items()

/var/folders/d0/gnksqzwn2fn46fjgrkp6045c0000gn/T/ipykernel_49841/938463883.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
      2 
      3 revd = {
----> 4         k: max((e for e in v if pd.notna(e)), key=lambda x: float(clean_currency(x)) if isinstance(x, str) else x)
      5         for k,v in d.items()
      6        }

ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Comment: And your question is how to get the maximum of an empty sequence?

Comment: @mkrieger1 1) why is it empty? I am missing something 2) How to get `max()` of the sequence?

Comment: Apparently `pd.notna(e)` is not true for all `e` in `v`. Or `v` is an empty sequence.

Comment: Because `(e for e in v if pd.notna(e))` is producing an empty sequence, namely, if all the elements in `v` are not `pd.notna(e)`, so, for example, `[np.nan]`

Comment: Looking at `d`, it seems to me as if `[np.nan]` would be one such `v` for which `pd.notna` is not true for all elements.

Comment: honestly, you can probably just remove that `pd.notna`, it shouldn't affect things

Comment: Note, using `numpy`/`pandas` here is pretty nonsensicle. You just want `float('nan')` and `import math` and `math.isnan`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Is there another way you'd do this? Could you respond with a solution and then I can try that on my entire dictionary? I could only post a small sample on SO.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are filtering all the `nan`s out, leaving you with an empty sequence in some case. But there is no need to filter nans, as far as I can tell. The reasonable response for the maximum of all nans is nan, which is already the behavior you'd get, so just use something like this:

```
from pprint import pprint

def clean_currency(x):
    """ If the value is a string, then remove currency symbol and delimiters
    otherwise, the value is numeric and can be converted
    """
    if isinstance(x, str):
       x = x.replace('$', '').replace(',', '')
    return float(x)



d = {
     'shores': ['$0.00'],
     'Broderick': ['$0.00', '$0.00', '$0.00'],
     '100 Broderick': ['$0.00', '$1,142,070.00', '$0.00', '$0.00', '$0.00'],
     '1001 Orange Grove': ['$0.00'],
     '1008 Hyde': [float('nan')]
    }


# Keep the highest value from the list.

revd = {
    k: max(v, key=clean_currency)
    for k,v in d.items()
}

pprint(revd, sort_dicts=False)
```

which outputs:

```
{'shores': '$0.00',
 'Broderick': '$0.00',
 '100 Broderick': '$1,142,070.00',
 '1001 Orange Grove': '$0.00',
 '1008 Hyde': nan}
```

Comment: `revd = {
        k: max(v, key=lambda x: float(clean_currency(x)) if isinstance(x, str) else x)
        for k,v in revDict.items()
       }`

Comment: @kms you could do that sure, but imo that is not ideal. Don't sacrifice readability for terseness